# What's the pattern attribute in paper-input-container?

Tags: regex, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to auto-validate the input in some `<paper-input-container>`'s `<input is="iron-input">` field, so that it follows a `dd.mm.yyyy` pattern. Can I do this with the `pattern` attribute?

I tried `pattern="^(\d{2}).\d{2}.(\d{4})$"` and `pattern="(1-9|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(20[1-3][0-9])"` together with `allowed-pattern="[\d.]"`, but that doesn't work.

Is the `pattern` attribute meant to support this use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`<paper-input>.pattern`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/paper-input#property-pattern) is ignored unless you do one of the following:

- Enable automatic input validation with [`<paper-input>.autoValidate`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/paper-input#property-autoValidate)

  ```
  <paper-input auto-validate
               pattern="^(\d{2}).\d{2}.(\d{4})$">
  </paper-input>
  ```

  [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yMzeGV?editors=1010)
- Manually call [`<paper-input>.validate()`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/paper-input#method-validate) (e.g., on button click)

  ```
  <paper-input id="input" pattern="..."></paper-input>
  <button on-tap="_validateInput">Validate</button>

  // script
  _validateInput: function() {
    this.$.input.validate();
  }
  ```

  [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/aJLNOK?editors=1010)
- Set `<paper-input>.required`, and use an [`<iron-form>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form) wrapper, which automatically calls `<paper-input>.validate()` on submit

  ```
  <form id="form" is="iron-form" ...>
    <paper-input required
                 pattern="..."></paper-input>
    <button on-tap="_submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  // script
  _submit: function() {
    this.$.form.submit(); // <-- auto validates required form inputs
  }
  ```

  [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bqopBw?editors=1010)

Comment: @atomikolex No problem :)